# Testing validity of Proxy servers concurrently

Tags: c#, beginner, asynchronous, http, status-monitoring

I am trying to test the validity of a few thousand public proxy servers quickly.  To do this, I am sending web requests using each proxy to a website such as example.com, and checking that no errors such as timeouts occur, and that the page contains a certain string value which I already know that site will contain.

Using a synchronous method like HttpWebRequest.GetResponse simply will not do for my large list.  So I am using HttpWebRequest.BeginGetResponse instead, and passing in an Action object called callback and invoking that callback upon completion or failure of the request.

I want to know if there is a better way to achieve the concurrency I require.  Using HttpWebRequest.GetResponseAsync does not actually decrease the time it takes to test the whole list, although it will not block the UI thread compared to GetResponse.

I haven't implemented input validation on some of classes yet, so please disregard that when answering.  I also haven't added a timeout check using ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject yet, disregard that as well.

```
namespace HelperLib
{
    public class Proxy
    {
        public string IP { get; set; }
        public int Port { get; set; }
        public bool IsValid { get; set; }

        public Proxy(string ip, int port)
        {
            //TODO Validate input.
            this.IP = ip;
            this.Port = port;
        }

        public void TestValidityAsync(ProxyTest test, Action<bool, Exception> callback)
        {
            var request = HttpWebRequest.Create(test.URL);
            request.Proxy = new WebProxy(this.ToString());
            WebUtility.GetResponseAsync(request, (requestState, ex) => {
                if (requestState.response != null && requestState.responseString.Contains(test.Validation))
                {           
                    if (test.Invalidation == null)
                    {
                        callback.Invoke(true, ex);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (!requestState.responseString.Contains(test.Invalidation))
                        {
                            callback.Invoke(true, ex);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            callback.Invoke(false, ex);
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    callback.Invoke(false, ex);
                }
            });
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return this.IP + ":" + this.Port;
        }

    }
}

namespace HelperLib
{
    public class ProxyTest
    {
        public string URL { get; set; }
        public string Validation { get; set; }
        public string Invalidation { get; set; }

        public ProxyTest(string url, string validation)
        {
            this.URL = url;
            this.Validation = validation;
        }

        public ProxyTest(string url, string validation, string invalidation)
        {
            this.URL = url;
            this.Validation = validation;
            this.Invalidation = invalidation;
        }
    }
}
namespace HelperLib
{
    public class WebUtility
    {

        public static void GetResponseAsync(WebRequest request, Action<RequestState, Exception> callback)
        {
            //Send a non-blocking asynchronous web request.
            var requestState = new RequestState();
            requestState.request = request;
            requestState.responseCallback = callback;
            requestState.request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(ResponseCallback), requestState);
        }

        private static async void ResponseCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            var requestState = (RequestState)ar.AsyncState;
            try
            {
                requestState.response = requestState.request.EndGetResponse(ar);
                requestState.responseStream = requestState.response.GetResponseStream();
                using (var sr = new StreamReader(requestState.responseStream))
                {
                    requestState.responseString = await sr.ReadToEndAsync();
                }
                requestState.responseCallback.Invoke(requestState, null);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                requestState.responseCallback.Invoke(requestState, ex);
            }
        }

    }
}

namespace HelperLib
{
    public class RequestState
    {
        public WebRequest request;
        public WebResponse response;
        public Action<RequestState, Exception> responseCallback;
        public StringBuilder responseBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        public Stream responseStream;
        public Byte[] responseBuffer = new Byte[1024];
        public string responseString;
    }
}
```

Speed comparison vs HttpClient

```
   private void MethodA()
    {
        ManualResetEvent mre = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 500;
        int responseCount = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
        {
            WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create("http://example.com");
            HelperLib.WebUtility.GetResponseAsync(req, (requestState, ex) =>
            {
                responseCount++;
                if (responseCount == iterations)
                {
                    mre.Set();
                }
            });
        }
        mre.WaitOne();
        Debug.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        //Outputs 816
    }

    private async void MethodB()
    {
        Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
            {
                string response = await client.GetStringAsync("http://example.com");
            }
        }
        sw.Stop();
        Debug.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        //Outputs 2744
    }
```

Comment: have you considered using `HttpClient` and its async API

Comment: @Nkosi Hi, I have tested throughput using HttpClient.GetStringAsync, and 100 requests took 2+ seconds.  My current implementation sent the same 100 requests in 800ms.  Considering scaling, I would rather choose the best performing solution.

Comment: was that 100 using `Task.WhenAll`?

Comment: @Nkosi I edited my question and showed my test using HttpClient (MethodB).  Thanks for taking the time to respond.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following based on the example originally provided

```
static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
private async Task MethodB() {
    Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    List<Task<string>> tasks = new List<Task<string>>();
    for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
        var task = client.GetStringAsync("http://example.com");
        tasks.Add(task);
    }
    var responses = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    sw.Stop();
    Debug.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);        
}
```

`HttpClient` should be created once and used for the entire lifecycle of the application.

Avoid `async void` functions. Instead have them return a `Task`.

Tasks can be executed simultaneously using `Task.WhenAll`.

As for scale, group the requests into manageable batches and execute them asynchronously.

You can add a cancellation token to time out any requests that take longer than a predefined duration.

This would mean that for a batch it will only go as long as the set time out.

Each request can be encapsulated in its own function to handle exceptions or response functionality.

Comment: Very helpful thanks.  I will test this shortly and if it performs as well or better than my own implementation using BeginGetResponse I will mark this as the answer.  It certainly is less complicating to write.

Comment: Wow, using your method it cut the time in half to 400ms.  You rock!